# Mysqli query insert issues

Tags: php, mysqli

Have a problem with a query not inserting properly.

When I have the line

```
mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "INSERT INTO emailerdata (`emailer_timestamp`,`emailer_promoID`,`emailer_name`,`emailer_username`,`emailer_usermd5`,`emailer_email`,`emailer_md5`,`emailer_reactionID`) VALUES ('$date','$promoID','$rec_info[2]','$row[1]','$usermd5','$rec_info[0]','$passmd5','$row[0]')") or die("Error: ". ((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)). "     with query ". mysqli_query);
```

on it's own, it inserts fine.  However when I try to check to see if the email address in my database has already been inserted with that particular promotion ID in a query, it doesn't insert.

I can't find what's wrong with the query, am sure it's something simple but it isn't showing an error on the or die?

```
$row_amt = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * from emailerdata where emailer_promoID='$promoID' and emailer_username='$downloadusername'");
    while($row4 !== mysqli_fetch_assoc($row_amt)) {     
    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "INSERT INTO emailerdata (`emailer_timestamp`,`emailer_promoID`,`emailer_name`,`emailer_username`,`emailer_usermd5`,`emailer_email`,`emailer_md5`,`emailer_reactionID`) VALUES ('$date','$promoID','$rec_info[2]','$row[1]','$usermd5','$rec_info[0]','$passmd5','$row[0]')") or die("Error: ". ((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)). "     with query ". mysqli_query); 
    }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);  
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: ah thank you that has produced a whole world of errors, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use function [mysqli_num_rows](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp) to check number of rows return by query

```
$row_amt = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * from emailerdata where emailer_promoID='$promoID' and emailer_username='$downloadusername'");
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($row_amt);
if($rowcount == 0) {     
    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "INSERT INTO emailerdata (`emailer_timestamp`,`emailer_promoID`,`emailer_name`,`emailer_username`,`emailer_usermd5`,`emailer_email`,`emailer_md5`,`emailer_reactionID`) VALUES ('$date','$promoID','$rec_info[2]','$row[1]','$usermd5','$rec_info[0]','$passmd5','$row[0]')") or die("Error: ". ((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)). "     with query ". mysqli_query); 
}else{
    echo 'Email is already registered.';
}
```